# Swiftui append to a struct array doesn't work

Tags: arrays, struct, swiftui, append

Im learning swiftui at this moment. But now i have come across a problem.
Im trying to append data to an array that is an struct.

```
struct outfit:Identifiable {
var id = UUID()
var user: String
var amount: Double
var rating: Double
}
```

and the other file

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseFirestore

struct rate: View {
private var db = Firestore.firestore()
@State var user = Auth.auth().currentUser
@State private var outfitcards = [outfit]()
@State private var cards = [1, 2, 3]
@State private var offset = [CGSize.zero, CGSize.zero]

init () {
    loadcards()
}

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { frame in
        ZStack{
            VStack {
                Text("outfit")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .padding()
                
                ZStack {
                    Text("No cards to show")
                        .frame(width: frame.size.width * 0.6, height: frame.size.width * 1.6)
                    
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "record.circle.fill")
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: "record.circle.fill")
                            .foregroundColor(.green)

                        
                    }
                    
    
                    ForEach(outfitcards) { index in
                        Text(index.user)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
func loadcards () {
    db.collection("rating").whereField("user", isNotEqualTo: user?.uid ?? "Error")
        .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                   let cuser = document.get("user") as! String
                    let camount = document.get("amount") as! Double
                   let crating = document.get("rating") as! Double
                    print("user=\(cuser) amount=\(camount) crating=\(crating)")
                    outfitcards.append(outfit(user: cuser, amount: camount, rating: crating))
                }
                print(outfitcards)
            }
         }
    }
}
```

It does print the username, the amount and the rating but then when i print the array itself it is giving me a []. So it doens't append. Also the for each loop is empty so that also means that the array is empty

and nothing is appended

Does anyone know what I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading data in a `View` like that is a dangerous practice and it'll get reset/reloaded any time that view is re-rendered (or even re-inited in this case).

Instead, move your code that loads the data to an `ObservableObject`:

```
struct Outfit:Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var user: String
    var amount: Double
    var rating: Double
}

class Loader : ObservableObject {
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    private var user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    @Published var outfitcards = [Outfit]()
    
    func loadcards () {
        db.collection("rating").whereField("user", isNotEqualTo: user?.uid ?? "Error")
            .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err.localizedDescription)")
                } else {
                    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        let cuser = document.get("user") as! String
                        let camount = document.get("amount") as! Double
                        let crating = document.get("rating") as! Double
                        print("user=\(cuser) amount=\(camount) crating=\(crating)")
                        self.outfitcards.append(Outfit(user: cuser, amount: camount, rating: crating))
                    }
                    print(self.outfitcards)
                }
            }
    }
}

struct Rate: View {
    @StateObject var loader = Loader()
    @State private var cards = [1, 2, 3]
    @State private var offset = [CGSize.zero, CGSize.zero]
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { frame in
            ZStack{
                VStack {
                    Text("outfit")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .padding()
                    ZStack {
                        Text("No cards to show")
                            .frame(width: frame.size.width * 0.6, height: frame.size.width * 1.6)
                        
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "record.circle.fill")
                                .foregroundColor(.red)
                            Spacer()
                            Image(systemName: "record.circle.fill")
                                .foregroundColor(.green)
                        }
                        ForEach(loader.outfitcards) { index in
                            Text(index.user)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.onAppear {
            loader.loadcards()
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the loader is responsible for making the database call. It updates a @Published property, which the View observes.

Note that I changed the capitalization of a few things (Rate, Outfit). In Swift, the common practice is to capitalize types (classes/structs/enums) and start variable names with lowercase letters.

Also probably worth noting that the way that you're casting the data from firebase (with `as!`) is dangerous and can crash your program if the data isn't in the format you expect. Better to use optional binding (`let user = document.get("user") as? String`)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is there you are updating @State value in initializing View, which you are doing in Wrong way, do like this onAppear:

```
    struct rate: View {
private var db = Firestore.firestore()
@State var user = Auth.auth().currentUser
@State private var outfitcards = [outfit]()
@State private var cards = [1, 2, 3]
@State private var offset = [CGSize.zero, CGSize.zero]


var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { frame in
        ZStack{
            VStack {
                Text("outfit")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .padding()
                
                ZStack {
                    Text("No cards to show")
                        .frame(width: frame.size.width * 0.6, height: frame.size.width * 1.6)
                    
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "record.circle.fill")
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: "record.circle.fill")
                            .foregroundColor(.green)

                        
                    }
                    
    
                    ForEach(outfitcards) { index in
                        Text(index.user)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .onAppear() { loadcards() }  // <<: Here
}
func loadcards () {
    db.collection("rating").whereField("user", isNotEqualTo: user?.uid ?? "Error")
        .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                   let cuser = document.get("user") as! String
                    let camount = document.get("amount") as! Double
                   let crating = document.get("rating") as! Double
                    print("user=\(cuser) amount=\(camount) crating=\(crating)")
                    outfitcards.append(outfit(user: cuser, amount: camount, rating: crating))
                }
                print(outfitcards)
            }
         }
    }
}
```